# About List in c#

Tags: c#, list, class

i have a class which name is `PlayerParameters` and the structure of my class is like that

```
 public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public string INFO { get; set; }
    public double GP { get; set; }
    public double MIN { get; set; }
```

this is the shortened version of my class, in my project this class has more property,

i have a list which name is `PlayerParametersList` and this list's type is `PlayerParameters` class, and i get some data from some web site with json format, i convert it and added to this list, so my list is like

```
TITLE = c#

INFO = something

GP = 1.4

MIN = 55.9
```

In C# if you want to reach INFO you have to write `PlayerParametersList.INFO` but i have lots of property, so i can't do this code to all property.

Is there any simplest way?

Because after that i am going to make some insert statements to sql and as you know the statement like that

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (i got 50 propertyso, i can't write all things in here) 
VALUES (i got 50 values so, i can't write all values in here);
```

My question is how can i reach values and the property of my PlayerParamatersList without coding `PlayerParametersList.INFO`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: 1) The terminology is wrong :). You mean "property" and not "attribute" (different things in C#/.NET). 2) You can use frameworks like `Entity Framework` or `NHibernate` that do the mapping from C# properties to SQL statements automatically by using reflection. If you don't want to use them, you can use reflection to do what you want but it's not going to be "simpler". just less typing.

Comment: Could you show a complete example, just with 2 or 3 attributes instead of 50? It's not really clear, at least to me, what problem you are having with this list, and I can't understand where it's defined: is it a member of the Player class or what?

Comment: You have 50 properties, fine. You spent time in declaring those 50 properties, You can use reflection, but that's brittle.

Comment: @kha thanks for terminolgy, i editted it now :) In frameworks can i do like i want to select 2. element of my list and add players table in mssql and this playerid row? i am asking because i didn't  use frameworks before

Comment: @PaoloTedesco i don't want to copy all of my class property for don't making this question longer :) PlayerParameters is a class, in main.cs i create a list and this list's type is PlayerParameters class, this class contains anything you can imagine about NBA PLAYERS STATS :D

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes you right, i did it once at the class but i don't want to do it again :D If there is no solution i am obliged to do same way :(

Comment: @ufuk.dogan Yes, You can specify which columns you want to retrieve in certain frameworks or just write stored procs that retrieve what you need and call them using the framework (most of them allow calling stored procs). Do some research on these frameworks and pick one that fits your requirements best. None of them will be as fast as doing it manually but generally (and I mean, generally, i.e. not universally applicable) the small performance penalty outweighs the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an "[Object-Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) Framework" which is a software layer between a SQL Database and a C# object model.

There is `EntityFramework` from MS or `NHibernate` to start with.

Comment: i didn't use any framework so i don't know what can i do with this :D

Comment: In frameworks can i do like i want to select 2. element of my list and add players table in mssql and this playerid row?

Comment: Read about it, learn about it, it is the way to go. And yes, these things are highly configurable.